# Silverstripe: DataList Filter equivalent of 'Value > x OR Value = y'

Tags: silverstripe

I understand that I can specify multiple values for my filter in a way such as:

```
xxx::get()->filter('FirstName', array('Sam', 'Sig'));
```

Which gives me the equivalent of:

```
... WHERE FirstName = 'Sam' OR FirstName = 'Sig'
```

However, there doesn't appear to be anyway of combining `OR`'s with the modifiers (`'LastVisited:GreaterThan' => '2011-01-01'`)

I need to be able to filter like so:

```
WHERE ExpiryDate > 29-11-2012 OR ExpiryDate IS NULL
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? I have read the docs but have not found the answer to my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always use the `where()` function if nothing else will do what you need.

```
xxx::get()->where("\"ExpiryDate\" > 29-11-2012 OR \"ExpiryDate\" IS NULL");
```

http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel#where-clauses